# Different Symfony projects, one database. How should we handle the entities?

Tags: php, database, symfony, entity

We have different symfony4 projects (readonly APIs) which uses the same database.
In every project we use, for example, the User Entity and the Groups Entity.
So, if we change the database (eg. add a new field), we have to change all the entities in all our projects. How can we solve this problem?

Should we create a Entity Bundle and install it with composer to every project? Or is there another solution?

Comment: your question is a bit broad, suggest to re-create it with your goals, why you have chosen this approach etc. and where you are specifically stuck. generally I recommend to have a shared bundle which deals with shared entities.

Comment: For what I understand I think the composer approach would do the job yes :)

Comment: Because the projects are different APIs on different hosts, but with one database. My problem is to change all the entities after a database change.

Comment: While a shared UserBundle might seem tempting it does not really address the underlying problem of why the entities are being changed in the first place.  Does each project suddenly have a need for all these changes?  How are the changes going to be used if only the entities were tweaked? How about templates and business logic?  Seems like your problems extend far beyond entities.

Comment: What kind of templates? We have no business logic, we have only some database queries. And yes all or the most of the projects need the changes.

Comment: The best explanation is the change from account number/bankcode to IBAN/BIX in Europe.
We have many APIs with an entity bankdata. 
1. BankInformation
2. Supplier
3. Customer
and so on. 
When the change took place, we have to change all the bankdata entities in all APIs. We only want to make these changes once.

Comment: One assumes that if a new property is added then the property will be used somewhere.  Perhaps displayed on a web page.  Maybe a report.  Perhaps you need the ability to set or update the value of the property.

Comment: No, inserting the data is done by an import. We only provide a readonly API.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best approach for implementing reusable code is to create bundles. That way you can easily reuse them and update them.